# Why are bitstrings without 00 of length n equals $Fib_{n+2}$?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, bit-strings

EDIT: $B_{n}$ denotes the number of bitstrings of length n without 00.

So I've been studying Discrete Math, and I came across the proof that $B_{n} = f_{n+2}$. What I do not understand about this is, why is it equal to the (n+2)th fib series? The book explains it in terms of matrices and tbh I don't quite understand it.

I tried counting $B_{4}$ and it was a equal to 8, which is $B_{1} + B_{2}$.

What I understood so far is, to build a bitstring of length n, you first need to know the bitstring of length n-1, and all the way until 1. So following that, a bitstring of length n (any bitstring), is equal to all combinations of bitstring n - 1 * 2, right? (Because you either add 1 or 0 in the last digit).

Is it the same of bistrings without 00? (although when I tried that, you had to make sure the combination of any two bistrings do not end and start with 0)

Comment: What is $B_n$? Please give your readers as much help as you can.

Comment: $B_4=B_2+B_3$, not $B_1+B_2$. $B_1=2, B_2=3, B_3=5$.

Comment: Take your recursion and add one parameter.
$$B_{n,0}:=\text{strings without $00$ of length $n$ that end in $0$}$$
$$B_{n,1}:=\text{strings without $00$ of length $n$ that end in $1$}$$
So $B_n=B_{n,0}+B_{n,1}$. Do the recurrence for the both of them and you will see more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_{n}$ be the number of bit strings of length n with no 00 that end in zero, and $Y_{n}$ be those that end in one.

Clearly $X_{1}$ and $Y_{1}$ are both 1.

Suppose we know $X_{k}$ and $Y_{k}$ and we wish to know $X_{k+1}$ and $Y_{k+1}$. Do you see why

$X_{k+1}$ = $Y_{k}$

$Y_{k+1}$ = $X_{k}$ + $Y_{k}$

?

Can you take the proof from here?

Answer (score 0):

To find the binary strings of length $n+1$ with no $00$ substring, you can either take a string with this property of length $n-1$ and add $10$ to the end, or you can take a string with this property of length $n$ and add $1$ to the end.

Comment: Why can you not take a string with this property of length n - 1 and add 11?

Comment: Because you've already counted that when you counted strings of length $n$ and added $1$. You don't want to count that string twice.

Comment: Just checking my understanding here: For a bitstring of length n+1 without 00, it either ends in 1, or 10. And if I want to do the opposite, which is bitstrings of no 11, I can say that it either ends in 0 or 01, right? So I have to take the bitstrings of n-1, and add 0. OR I have to add 01 to the end, so I have to take strings of length n-2 that do not have 11. Is that correct?